# What code do I need to input to close a Selection Box once I click a button within the box?

Tags: excel, macros, commandbutton, vba

I have a command box that I have two drop down selections inside of, and after I select my two options, I have an "Update" button within the Selection Box. I am attempting to write a code that would cause the Selection Box to close once I click "Update." Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Share your code so far and tell us how it is you're stuck.

Comment: I am hoping to just get an additional line of code to cause the selection box to close once I click a button within the box. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to share my code because it is confidential. Any suggestions would be very helpful though for force closing the selection box once I click the button!

Comment: selectionBox.close?? `not allowed to share my code because it is confidential` that's hilarious because there's nothing in that code that's worth any value unless you named your selectionbox after nuclear launch codes....

Comment: Without code, it is hard to know what you are referring to.  Is this a user form with two combo boxes and a command button?

Comment: Yes, it is a user form with two combo boxes and a command button. I apologize about not being able to share my code. I'm not looking to alter any existing code though, just trying to add this one element to the end.

Answer (score 0):

If your userform is called "UserForm1" you can use `Unload(UserForm1)`

This discharges it though. If you just want it to now be visible it is `UserForm1.Hide`

Comment: Do I put this line at the end of my coding?

Comment: You put this code at whichever point you want the userform to go away. Presumably at the end of the code that is triggered when you click "Update".